# Check if datagridview cell is null or empty

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have to change the background color of the cells , when their value is string or empty, this is the code i have write similar to other codes here :

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dataGridView1.RowCount; rowIndex++)
            {
             string conte = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString()  ;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(conte))
                {
                // dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].Style.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                }
                else
                 { dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].Style.BackColor = Color.Orange; }
        }
```

the dataset is complete , show me the datagridview populated and the show me this error: [image]

How can i fix this?? Have another way to write the code?

Comment: If the DGV is AllowUserToAddRows = True then you are iterating one row too many.  Covered in the NRE answer

Comment: use debug, if you have a problem after that there is question how to solve NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 7):

I would iterate through the cells using something like the following..

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    var cell = dgRow.Cells[7];
    if (cell.Value != null)   //Check for null reference
    {
        cell.Style.BackColor = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString()) ? 
            Color.LightCyan :   
            Color.Orange;       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `ToString()`. See [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709656/nullreferenceexception-in-string-isnullorwhitespace-and-string-isnullorempty)

The below code is enough.

```
string conte = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].Value;
```

Also you may try something like:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[7].Value as string))
```